# How to trouble shoot PS/2 mouse not working on a Japanese Dos 5.5 based machine

Tags: dos

Have problem with connecting a PS/2 mouse to a Japanese DOS 5.5 system. How to determining whether the necessary drivers are already installed and, if not, how to install them. The computer has a functioning PS/2 mouse port, so the issue is not related to hardware.

Checking if the port is functional and the mouse is functional as well.

Comment: How do you know that the PS/2 port is functioning correctly if the mouse is having problems? Did you plug the mouse into the correct PS/2 port? One is for the keyboard and the other is for the mouse. Some systems, more than you think, can't handle the items swapped. Have you tried the 'tried and true' [CuteMouse driver](https://cutemouse.sourceforge.net/)? A note: do not hot-plug the mouse or keyboard. Always make sure the machine is off when plugging something into the PS/2 ports. Older PS/2 ports can be damaged if you hot-plug an item.